# Setup docker to use php-fpm + Laravel + supervisor in one container

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose, supervisord

I need to have supervisor for my laravel queues. But supervisor starts from root user, and I want to start php from another user for safety. I could not find solution to start php in another way, like a standart user from image - www-data.

And I also have files with backend owner. I read that it's safer to have php files with one owner and start php-fpm with another

Question: is it normal to work in producation with www-data user for php-fpm or I have to have another user for it. Or maybe I can  unite php-fpm with supervisor(and cron in future) in another way? And if I have to change user how to start php with another user? 
Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    git \
    curl \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
   libpq-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    supervisor \
    sudo


# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN pecl install -o -f redis \
&&  rm -rf /tmp/pear \
&&  docker-php-ext-enable redis

# Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install intl pdo pdo_pgsql pgsql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd zip
# Get latest Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 backend
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g backend backend

# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY . /var/www

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=backend:backend . /var/www


RUN ["chmod", "+x", "./my_wrapper_script.sh"]
RUN ["chown", "-R", "www-data:www-data", "./storage/framework"]
RUN ["chown", "-R", "www-data:www-data", "./storage/logs"]

COPY --chown=root:root docker-compose/app/supervisor.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ./my_wrapper_script.sh
```

Docker-compose

```
version: 3.7
services:

    app:
        build:
          context: ./
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        image: didido
        container_name: didido-app
        restart: unless-stopped
        working_dir: /var/www/

        tty: true
        environment:
            SERVICE_NAME: app
            SERVICE_TAGS: dev
        volumes:
          - ./:/var/www
        networks:
          - didido
    db:
      image: postgis/postgis:14-3.1
      restart: always
      container_name: didido-db
      networks:
        - didido
      environment:
        - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_DATABASE}
        - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USERNAME}
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      volumes:
        - ../2. Init Database:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
        - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres -d didido"]
          interval: 10s
          timeout: 5s
          retries: 5
          start_period: 10s
    nginx:
        image: nginx:1.17-alpine
        container_name: didido-nginx
        restart: unless-stopped
        tty: true
        ports:
          - 80:80
        depends_on:
            - nodejs
        volumes:
          - ./:/var/www
          - ./docker-compose/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
        networks:
          - didido

networks:
    didido:
        driver: bridge
```

my_wrapper_script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# Start the first process
php-fpm &

# Start the second process
supervisord &

# Wait for any process to exit
wait -n

# Exit with status of process that exited first
exit $?
```

Comment: Why did you add --chown=root:root  to your copying supervisor.conf  command? I didn't use it anytime. I wonder why did you do that.

Comment: Supervisor conf must have a root rights. Because supervisor starts from root user

Comment: I never used it in the dockerfiles I created before and I didn't have any problems. I checked other dockerfiles from github. They don't use it. Have you tried without adding this?

Comment: Yes it works. It has root permissions